# Reading the information in an unknown data file type

Tags: decode

I have a data file that has been generated by an application as an output of results to some tests.

I would like to be able to read the information contained in the file but it is encoded in a format which I presume to be some kind of binary.

Is there a simple way to read the information in this file?

I am not a programmer so I am hoping the solution lies somewhere in a converter/translator etc.